# Why doesn't the authentication work?

Tags: authentication-authorization

I am using Rest web service . I CREATED a view called ART and specified its path (/viewpath) and I set the  http baisc authentication within that view's structure such that the results will be accessible only for a user whose role is RESTADMIN . Everything works fine when I curl using the path of that view and the username and password of the user (of role restadmin) :

```
curl http://username:password@example.com/viewpath
```

However , when I try to get a simple article using its nid :

```
curl http://example.com/node/2?_format=hal_json
```

I get no results and "The used authentication method is not allowed on this route" . Even when I put the username and password as before I still get this error. I do realize that the authentication I have set is just for the view ART. But I can't find the solution to let the other link work any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the latter uses `hal_json`, you need to do it like this

```
curl --request GET --user myusername:mypassword --header 'Accept: application/hal+json' \
http://example.com/node/2?_format=hal_json
```

For more info, see [Using other authentication protocols](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/using-other-authentication-protocols#s-get-example-with-curl-and-http-basic).

Comment: thankkk youu !!